# Linq to sql order by a string that is not a property of the object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, linq

I have a category model with the following fields;

```
ID, Name
```

`Name` field is populated by a resource file which I have an extension method is called `Translate(int languageID)`, following code obviously doesn't work

```
IEnumerable<Category> categories = db.Categories.OrderBy(w=>w.Name.Translate(1));
```

I want to order categories by string that is returned by the `Translate` method. How can I achieve this?

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Since you used a variable named db, I'm going to presume that the reason your query doesn't work is that it is a query against the database, and your database query translator refuses to translate your Translate method into the language of the database.  You could have described the error you are getting and I wouldn't have to guess.

If my guess is correct, pull the records into memory by enumerating the query first, then call the method.  Like this:

```
IEnumerable<Category> categories = db.Categories
  .ToList()
  .OrderBy(w=>w.Name.Translate(1));
```

Comment: beware, this will select and materialize to objects whole table.. on the other hand, in his question he probably wants to do that...

Answer (score 0):

Because the Name property is not set yet, you might have to create an List with the translated names, then sort that.

```
IEnumerable<Category> unsorted = db.Categories.get(); //If get doesn't exist, use whatever method to return the whole list
foreach(var w in unsorted)
{
    w.____ = w.Name.Translate(1); //some property of each category needs to be assigned whatever value this returns
}

IEnumerable categories = unsorted.OrderBy(w => w.Name.Value); //Replace "Value" with whatever stores the actual string
```